# Unable to use apt-get: raspberrypi-net-mods is missing

Tags: raspbian, apt

I've installed `2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie` and trying to `upgrade apt-get`.

The problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'raspberrypi-net-mods' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I already tried to re-install `raspberrypi-net-mods` with:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get remove --purge raspberrypi-net-mods
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-net-mods
```

But nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why: I flashed raspbian images to SD card using `ApplePi-Baker`.

Switched to [`Etcher`](https://github.com/resin-io/etcher), all OK with it.

Maybe `ApplePi-Baker` needs some tweaking with new Raspbian versions.

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again year for year.

Comment: @Ingo Sorry, I am a novice, I will pay attention to it later.

Comment: No problem :-) This site and Raspberry Pi is made to learn hardware and software issues and show people, how Linux works.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a file corruption issue with the 2017-07-05 images of raspbian-jessie. Found a solution [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=187936&sid=143feadede9ffbce070127663d77fab1#p1186861) that doesn't involve the complete annihilation of your OS. Simply create a new file in a text editor, copy + paste the code block below, save it as `newline_fixer.py`, and as it states in the header,  run `sudo python newline_fixer.py` from a terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/python


# 8th November, 2009
# update manager failed, giving me the error:
#       'files list file for package 'xxx' is missing final newline' for every package.
# some Googling revealed that this problem was due to corrupt files(s) in /var/lib/dpkg/info/
# looping though those files revealed that some did not have a final new line
# this script will resolve that problem by appending a newline to all files that are missing it
# NOTE: you will need to run this script as root, e.g. sudo python newline_fixer.py

import os

dpkg_path = '/var/lib/dpkg/info/'
paths = os.listdir(dpkg_path)
for path in paths:
    path = dpkg_path + path
    f = open(path, 'a+')
    data = f.read()
    if len(data) > 1 and data[-1:] != '\n':
        f.write('\n')
        print 'added newline character to:', path
    f.close()
```